# Set zero axes in R

Tags: r

How can one force the visualisation of the zero axes *y*=0, *x*=0 in R, removing the external ones siding the plot? I want to obtain the same effect that one can have for example in Gnuplot with `set xzeroaxis, set yzeroaxis`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I have solved my own question as follows:

```
f<-function(x) x^3-2*x

# take the axes off first
plot(f,-2,2, axes=FALSE)

# re-set the axes at a given point (pos=0)
axis(1, pos=0, at=c(-2,-1,0,1,2))
axis(2, pos=0, at=c(-4,-2,2,4))
```

produces the below, which is what I had in mind (labels and the rest can be then adjusted at will).

[image: axes at zero]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using by suppressing the default axes by using `axes=FALSE` and then using `axis` to draw horizontal and vertical lines to represent the axes.

```
# example plot
plot(-2:2, -2:2, axes=FALSE)

# add yaxis at position zero and rotate labels 45deg
axis(side=2, pos=0, las=1, lty="dashed")

# x axis
axis(side=1, at=c(-2,-1,1,2), pos=0, lty="dashed")
```

This produces

[image]